# What's the idiomatic way of testing a list with dynamic content using react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-testing-library

New to RTL and trying to understand how to do things idiomatically. I have a list with a dynamic element (it appears in some rows and not others).

Here's the component:

```
import React from 'react'
export default function DummyList ({ items }) {
  return <div>
    {items.map(item => <ListItem item={item} key={item.name} />)}
  </div>
}

export function ListItem ({ item: { name, isActive } }) {
  return <div data-testid='list-item'>
    <span>{name}</span>
    {isActive && <span>Active!</span>}
  </div>
}
```

and here's the test

```
import React from 'react'
import { render, getByText, queryByText, getAllByTestId } from '@testing-library/react'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'
import DummyList from './index'

describe('DummyList', () => {
  it('renders', async () => {
    const items = [
      { name: 'Unused Item' },
      { name: 'Used Item', isActive: true }
    ]

    render(<DummyList items={items} />)

    const listItems = getAllByTestId(document.body, 'list-item')
    expect(listItems).toHaveLength(2)

    expect(getByText(listItems[0], 'Unused Item')).toBeInTheDocument()
    expect(queryByText(listItems[0], 'Active!')).not.toBeInTheDocument()

    expect(getByText(listItems[1], 'Used Item')).toBeInTheDocument()
    expect(queryByText(listItems[1], 'Active!')).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

Questions

1) Is there a way to avoid using data-testid in this scenario? Or is this a reasonable use of that escape hatch?

2) More generally, is there a more idiomatic way of using RTL for testing this kind of component?

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I would render your list using `ul` and `li` tags to make it more semantic. If for some reason you can't do that you can still add the `aria-role` attributes. Once that's done you can use `getAllByRole('listitem')` to get the elements:

```
describe('DummyList', () => {
  it('render the items', async () => {
    const items = [
      { name: 'Unused Item' },
      { name: 'Used Item', isActive: true }
    ]

    // You can get the query methods directly from render
    const { getAllByRole } = render(<DummyList items={items} />)

    const listItems = getAllByRole('listitem')
    expect(listItems).toHaveLength(2)

    // I use a `forEach` to make the test dynamic in case we decide
    // to generate items dynamically in the future
    // This method is also implicitly testing the order
    listItems.forEach((item, index) => {
      // You can import wihthin from @testing-library/react
      const { getByText, queryByText } = within(item)
      const { name, isActive } = items[index]
      expect(getByText(name)).toBeInTheDocument()
      isActive
        ? expect(getByText('Active!')).toBeInTheDocument()
        : expect(queryByText('Active!')).not.toBeInTheDocument()
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: I didn't find a way to use the listitem role testing react-native components. The react-testing-library complains that listitem is not a valid role.

I end up selecting the listItems by the testID, e.g. getAllByTestId(/prefix-/), supposing each item has a testID like "prefix-N".